# What happens on a centos 8 server when systemd-logind is turned off?

Tags: ssh, systemd, login, vsftpd, centos8

I have a centos 8 server setup which should provide sftp (openssh) and ftp (vsftp) transfers but no login shell to multiple users.
To tell vsftpd the root for chroot jails I have to add a dot to the users home path in `/etc/passwd` (`/home/./user01` for example).

As long as the users home path contains a dot approximately every second sftp login of this user has a delay of 25 seconds and there is the following error message in sshds journal:

```
pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: Connection timed out
```

Disabling systemd-logind by masking it (`systemctl mask systemd-logind.service`) solves the delay problem, so I suspect a bug in systemd in connection with dots in home paths.

I'm considering turning of systemd-logind permanently but I'm not sure which implications that will have to other services or systemd on the server.

I found a section in the [pam_systemd module documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html#Description) which describes some actions like creating/deleting a `/run/user/$UID` directory or managing users systemd scopes it will do on login or logout.

My question is: Are there any other implications that I have to expect when I disable systemd-logind service permanently?

Comment: To disable systemd-logind you have to mask the service and disable the systemd PAM module (pam_systemd). You can do it with the following commands:
systemctl mask systemd-logind.service
pam-auth-update ;should be generally safe to do.

Comment: @overmind
`pam-auth-update` seems to be debian or ubuntu specific. Is authselect on EL/CENTOS something similar? Where can pam_systemd be deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment, but apparently it takes less reputation to make an answer, oddly.  25 seconds is the default Dbus timeout, FWIW.  Perhaps run (as root)

busctl monitor

in a shell and see what is going on when it's timing out?
Are you leaking sessions?

loginctl list-sessions

show?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/523411)